# ¿Cómo pausar textos hasta introducir enter en consola?

Tags: java, consola

Imprimo un texto en consola mediante `System.out.println()`, la siguiente instrucción es otro `System.out.println()`, pero no quiero que esa instrucción se ejecute hasta que se presione <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Lo intenté con el siguiente código, pero no funcionó:

```
System.out.println("hasta aqui se detiene mi programa y espera el enter");
String espacio ="";
String espacio1 ="";
espacio = S.next();
if (espacio.equals(espacio1)== false){
    System.out.println("este es el texto que no quiero que aparezca hasta dar enter");
}
System.out.println("mas texto");
```

Comment: Tenes que intercalar los inputs con los outputs

Answer (score 4):

Si empleas Scanner mejor leer la entrada con ReadLine para tomar también espacios.
Si desea pausar la entrada o salida de textos hasta que no se presione enter puede probar esto , Mientras no se presione `enter`, no avanzamos para eso usamos `dowhile`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String entrada  ="";
 do{
    entrada  = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(entrada);
 }
 while(!entrada.equals("")); 
 System.out.println("SE PRESIONÓ LA TECLA ENTER");
```

Comment: Hola, mas o menos te entendí, aunque el que expusiste aquí no me funciono, pero lo hice con readline, no lo entiendo aun, pero funciona perfectamente, ya lo estudiare poco a poco, gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien se encuentra con mi mismo problema, lo solucione aunque no lo entiendo del todo, tengo que seguir estudiando por supuesto, utilice el siguiente código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

De ahí en adelante, cada vez que quería que se pausara el programa hasta introducir enter usaba este método:

```
String sTexto = br.readLine();
```

Asi seria la solución completa:

```
System.out.println("texto1");
String sTexto4 = br.readLine();
System.out.println("texto2");   
String sTexto5 = br.readLine();
System.out.println("texto3");
String sTexto6 = br.readLine();
System.out.println("texto4"); 
String sTexto7 = br.readLine();
System.out.println("texto5");
String sTexto8 = br.readLine();
```

Nótese que cada que utilizo el método `br.redline()` cambio el nombre al String. Creo que mas o menos esto es lo que me suguirio un compañero en mi pregunta al sugerir usar `readline`

Answer (score 0):

Buenas despues de mucho buscar termine usando este modelo y funciona ok!

```
static public void pressAnyKeyToContinue()
      { 
          String seguir;
          Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Press Enter key to continue...");
          try
            {
             seguir = teclado.nextLine();
            }   
         catch(Exception e)
          {}  
     }
```

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación de tu código para que el resto de la comunidad comprenda como esto soluciona la pregunta expuesta